# Generate liquibase change log using java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to output a `changelog xml` file through `java`.

I am not sure as to what I need to pass as parameters to the following method.

```
liquibase.generateChangeLog("chris", changeLogWriter, outputStream, snapshotTypes);
```

`Chris` is the `schema name` in `Oracle 11g XE`.

I don't want to generate on command line. I want to use application I am building to generate it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        String userName = "chris";
        String userPwd = "Liberty123";

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, userPwd);
            System.out.println("success");
            Liquibase liquibase = null;
            try {
                Database liqui_oracle = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(c));
                liquibase = new Liquibase("", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), liqui_oracle);
                liquibase.generateChangeLog("chris", changeLogWriter, outputStream, snapshotTypes);
```

Comment: I tried to format the code but it doesn't seem full code here. Fixed gramar

Comment: You're missing a few `catch`es and right-braces.  Is this the full code you're trying to use?

Comment: Also I do hope that isn't a  real password.  Even if no one can access the database, you should always practice good security and never expose passwords to anyone.